# How to add filter parameters in angular js (using or )?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

i want to add filter parameter to my code. 
i know how to add multiple filter parameters using &. But i want to give two options for a variable ( the sql query would be ...`where Account In("ABC,"DEF")`).

```
dataSource: {
                type: "jsonp",

                transport: {
                    read: function(e) {
                        reportService.WebAPI('ByIUAct', {
                            Activity:'ABC',
                            Activity:'DEF',                       

                            OrderBy: getOrderBy(e.data.sort)
                        }).then(function (d) {
                            $scope.data = d;
                            e.success(d.Data);
                            });
                    }
                },
```

How do i give the two filter parameters to my api url? The above code brings error.

thanks

Answer (score -1):

This did it

```
 reportService.WebAPI('ByIUAct', {
                            Activity:'ABC, DEF',
                         }
```

Comment: How is this related to an AngularJS filter (if it's at all related to Angular in general)?